Não consigo estilizar o valor da cidade e data
Esse é o código que estou utilizando, mas não consigo estilizar a cidade nem a data. Queria colocar negrito + background preto só na cidade e a data de outra cor.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {

      $.ajax({
        url: "https://ipinfo.io/json",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (location) {
          var data = new Date(),
            dia = data.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
            mes = (data.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
            ano = data.getFullYear();
          
          data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano;

          //AQUI altera o texto ANTES do nome da cidade
          textoAntesCidade = 'Você e algumas pessoas próximo a ';
          //AQUI altera o texto DEPOIS do nome da cidade
          textoDepoisCidade = ' foram selecionadas para ver este vídeo até o dia ';

          mostrarData = true; //SE não quiser que a data apareça é só mudar o valor 'true' para 'false' e vice-versa para mostrar novamente 
          
          if(location.city)
            $('#container-cidade').html(textoAntesCidade + location.city + textoDepoisCidade + (mostrarData ? data : ''));
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #container-cidade {
      padding: 1rem;
      width: 100%;
      /* AQUI altera a cor de fundo da caixa */
      background-color: #F33E99;
      /* AQUI altera a cor da letra */
      color: #FFFFFF;
      display: inline-table;
      /* AQUI altera o tamanho da letra */
      font-size: 15px;
      /* AQUI altera a altura da caixa */
      height: 13px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: inherit;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div id="container-cidade">Aguarde um momento...</div>


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
